# Problem while retrieving info from Firebase Database IOS

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from my Database but I'm having some problems, this is my database structure:

[image]

And here is my code

```
var ref : DatabaseReference
        var idString = [String]()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("idUsers").observe(.value){ (snapshot) in
            let id = snapshot.value as? String

            if let ids = id {
                idString.append(ids)
                print(ids)
            }
        }
```

But no data is going into my array, I have been trying some solutions but no one works, please help! These are my rules by the way, they are public by default.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `idUsers` contains multiple child nodes, you need to loop over the results in your code. Something like this:

```
ref.child("idUsers").observe(.value){ (snapshot) in
    for userSnapshot in in snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
        let id = userSnapshot.value as? String
        print(id)

        idString.append(id)
    }
    print(ids)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one thing more why do you have to do .allObjects as? [Snapshot] instead of .allObjects?

Comment: `.allObjects` exposes an array of any time. Since I want to access `.value` in the loop, the elements need to be `DataSnapshot`. You can do that on the loop level as I've done here, or by doing a casting conversion inside the loop for each element individually. Btw: if you simply remove the cast, you can see what it then does.

Answer (score 0):

```
**For creating database structure**

`override func viewDidLoad() {
var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] user, error in
                guard self != nil else { return }
                ref.child("users").setValue(["test1": "abc",
                                             "test2": "efg",
                                             "test3": "hij"])

            }
        }
}`

**// For retrieving data from firebase**

ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
            for item in postDict {
                print(item)
            }
        })
```